# How to work with multiple spinners using URLs?

Tags: android, json, http, android-spinner

In my application I'm working with two spinners first spinner contains data like **Department and id** and second spinner contains **deficiency and id**, here I am working with some URL as below.

http://182.18.163.39/m/def.php?issue=1

This URL gives me first spinner values. On selecting a value from the first spinner the data related to that value will come in second spinner.

Here is my second URL which gives second spinner values.

"http://182.18.163.39/m/def.php?issue=2&dept="+dept_id

In this URL I want to pass the id from the first URL, here is my problem I am able to get all values from first spinner. When I select one value from first spinner it doesn't give me related values in the second spinner.
Anyone give me an example code for solving this.

Here is the code:

```
  //Department spinner
    Spinner spinner;
    String URL="http://182.18.163.39/train/m/def.php?issue=1";
    ArrayList<String> Department;
    String uid;

    //Deficiency category spinner
    Spinner spinner2;
    String URL2 = "http://182.18.163.39/train/m/def.php?issue=2&dept="+dept_id;
    ArrayList<String>Deficiency;
    String defid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_deficiency);

        //spinner for department
        Department = new ArrayList<>();
        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.select_department);
        loadSpinnerData(URL);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String department = spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),department,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // DO Nothing here
            }
        });

        //spinner for deficiency
        Deficiency = new ArrayList<>();
        spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.deficiency_category);
        loadSpinnerDeficiency(URL2);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String deficiency =   spinner2.getItemAtPosition(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),deficiency,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // DO Nothing here
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String department = jsonobject.getString("Department");
                dept_id = jsonobject.getString("ID");
                Department.add(department);
            }

            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewDeficiency.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Department));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void loadSpinnerDeficiency(String url2) {

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://182.18.163.39/train/m/def.php?issue=2&dept="+dept_id);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String defcat = jsonobject.getString("Deficiency");
                defid = jsonobject.getString("ID");

                Deficiency.add(defcat);
            }

            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewDeficiency.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Deficiency));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

here is my json response of first URL:

```
[{
    "Department": "Select Department",
    "ID": ""
}, {
    "Department": "Engg North",
    "ID": "1"
}, {
    "Department": "DIESEL SHED",
    "ID": "2"
}, {
    "Department": "S &amp; T",
    "ID": "3"
}, {
    "Department": "SAFETY",
    "ID": "4"
}, {
    "Department": "Srdenwest",
    "ID": "5"
}, {
    "Department": "enggwest",
    "ID": "6"
}, {
    "Department": "Engg central",
    "ID": "7"
}, {
    "Department": "electmaint",
    "ID": "8"
}, {
    "Department": "Operating",
    "ID": "9"
}, {
    "Department": "Security",
    "ID": "10"
}, {
    "Department": "Diesel  Shed",
    "ID": "11"
}, {
    "Department": "Electric Loco shed",
    "ID": "12"
}, {
    "Department": "C &amp; W",
    "ID": "13"
}, {
    "Department": "trso",
    "ID": "14"
}, {
    "Department": "trdohe",
    "ID": "15"
}, {
    "Department": "engg",
    "ID": "16"
}, {
    "Department": "commercial",
    "ID": "17"
}, {
    "Department": "engg South",
    "ID": "18"
}, {
    "Department": "Mechanical",
    "ID": "19"
}]
```

And here is my json response of second URL:

```
[{
    "Deficiency": "Select Deficiency",
    "ID": ""
}, {
    "Deficiency": "Engg",
    "ID": "1"
}, {
    "Deficiency": "Track",
    "ID": "25"
}, {
    "Deficiency": "LCs",
    "ID": "26"
}, {
    "Deficiency": "Misc",
    "ID": "43"
}, {
    "Deficiency": "",
    "ID": "NULL"
}]
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using

Comment: Please add your both request response code.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: i updated my json responses also

Comment: It doesn't give you a correct data because you are not updating your `URL2`. try to put your `loadSpinnerDeficiency(URL2);` and change to `loadSpinnerDeficiency(URL2 + departmentId);` inside your `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener onItemSelected`.

Comment: thanks for this replay but here is a problem when i am passing departmentId it doesn't giving me the correct output because that departmentId value giving from the for loop which is last value of json array so can you help me to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shuold create a custom object like

```
 private HashMap<String,String>departmentMap=new HashMap<>();
private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {

    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String department = jsonobject.getString("Department");
            uid = jsonobject.getString("ID");
            Department.add(department);
            departmentMap.put(department,uid);
        }

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewDeficiency.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Department));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and modify your firstSpinner onclick like

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
            String department=spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),department,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String id=departmentMap.get(department);
            loadSpinnerDeficiency(URL2,id);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView){
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });
```

now you can use id in loadSpinnerDeficiency method to get proper response

```
 private void loadSpinnerDeficiency(String url2,String uid) {

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://182.18.163.39/train/m/def.php?issue=2&dept="+uid);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String defcat = jsonobject.getString("Deficiency");
                defid = jsonobject.getString("ID");

                Deficiency.add(defcat);
            }

            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewDeficiency.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Deficiency));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this replay it's working fine, but here is a small problem when i select one value from first spinner it is giving related values in second spinner. but after selection i want change value of first spinner it is carrying the values of first and second values of spinner1. if i change the value of spinner1 value of spinner are also change how to do it

Comment: if i change item of first spinner it is still showing the related values of first item values in spinner 2 how to solve it help me please